# how do i check if user input contains a symbol (+, -, *, /)

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace first_console_app
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Welcome to Calculator! Please input wether you would like to Add (+), Subtract (-), Times (*//astersik) or divice (/)");
            Console.ReadLine()
        }
    }
}
```

My current code, im making a calculator as my first ever application (i made a bot you can talk to in python but im completely new to c#, and im learning c++

Comment: It's hard to say how to solve your problem because you didn't provide your user input processing code

Comment: For starters, lookup the information page on how `ReadLine` works. Then look up string manipulation. There are many examples online.

Comment: take a look at making a simple [calculator app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netcore-3.1) returns a string that you can use with a `switch` statement to determine the operator:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

switch (input)
{
    case "+":
        ...
        break;

    case "-":
        ...
        break;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, i managed to write my first applidation without youtube! and i only needed help from 1 thing (here)